# Selenium 3.0 not working with Firefox 51.0.1

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I am running a simple program in java with eclipse 3.0(Firefox Browser)..But after running, I am getting following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property;

Can anyone please give me the workaround to run on firefox.
Note: Before all programs were running fine but after updation in firefox, getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first download GeckoDriver. After that, you can either add it to the PATH variable in environment variables sections, or you can set the path using "webdriver.gecko.driver" property. Check the below article for the steps -

http://www.automationtestinghub.com/selenium-3-0-launch-firefox-with-geckodriver/

Comment: Excellent!!! now code working...thanks!!!